# Python and mod_wsgi path issue

Tags: apache-2.2, python, mod-wsgi, aix, mercurial

I have an AIX 6.1 system that I've compiled and installed:

- Apache 2.2.21 (into /usr/local/mercurial)
- Python 2.7.2 (into /usr/local/bin and /usr/local/lib)
- mod_wsgi 3.3 (with the AIX fix #1 described [here](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/issues/detail?id=212))
- Mercurial 2.0 (system-wide)

However, when Apache starts, I get the following message in error_log:

```
IOError: invalid Python installation: unable to open /usr/local/bin/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile (No such file or directory)
```

See the problem? `bin/lib` doesn't exist. `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/config/Makefile` *does* exist though. However, I can't figure out where it's getting that path from. Here's the environment variables I've got:

```
PYTHONHOME=/usr/local/bin
PYTHONPATH=/usr/local/lib/python2.7
LIBPATH="/usr/local/mercurial/lib:$LIBPATH"
PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/lib:$PATH
LDR_CNTRL="MAXDATA=0x80000000"
AIXTHREAD_SCOPE=S
AIXTHREAD_MUTEX_DEBUG=OFF
AIXTHREAD_RWLOCK_DEBUG=OFF
AIXTHREAD_COND_DEBUG=OFF
SPINLOOPTIME=1000
YIELDLOOPTIME=8
MALLOCMULTIHEAP=considersize,heaps:8
```

I've tried all sorts of combinations with and without `PYTHONHOME`, `PYTHONLIB` and `PATH` in envvars. My `PATH`, in case it matters is:

```
/usr/bin:/etc:/usr/sbin:/usr/ucb:/usr/bin/X11:/sbin:/usr/opt/ifor/bin:/usr/local/bin:.
```

Comment: I created a 'lib' directory under /usr/local/bin and then created a link to /usr/local/lib/python2.7 just to see if it would accept it temporarily. Now it's moved on to complaining about /usr/local/bin/include/python2.7/pyconfig.h which obviously doesn't exist. It should be going to /usr/local/include. Where is it getting all of these invalid paths from?

Comment: Take out both the PYTHONHOME and PYTHONPATH variables completely and what do you get? PYTHONHOME is set wrong and PYTHONPATH shouldn't be needed.

Answer (score 0):

`PYTHONHOME` shouldn't be need. Also, try setting it to `/usr/local` (the default).

From the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/using/cmdline.html#environment-variables):

> By default, the libraries are searched in prefix/lib/pythonversion and 
>   exec_prefix/lib/pythonversion, where prefix and exec_prefix are installation-dependent
>   directories, both defaulting to /usr/local.
>
> When PYTHONHOME is set to a single directory, its value replaces both prefix and 
>   exec_prefix.